# Not clearing the data after form submission in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a registration form once user submit the form not clearing the data and it is not displaying the success message as well.here the code which i have written for registration form.

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->lang->load('error_messages', 'english');
    $this->load->model(VERSION . DOCTOR_MODEL_FOLDER . 'Doctor_model', 'doctors');
    $this->load->helper('gmaps');
    $this->load->library('locations');
}
 public function createAccount() {
    $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
    $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');        
    $email = $this->input->post('email_id');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $phone_number = $this->input->post('phone_number_with_ext');        
    $reg_no = $this->input->post('reg_no');    
    $regDetails = array(
        'first_name' => $first_name,
        'last_name' => $last_name,
        'email_id' => $email,
        'password' => $password,
        'reg_no' => $reg_no,
        'mobile_no' => $phone_number,            
    );
    $regMessage = $this->doctors->register($regDetails);
    //if registration done successfully
    if (is_string($regMessage)) {
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['response'] = $phone_number;

    } else {
        //if there is error
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['error_msg'] = $regMessage;
    }
    die(json_encode($data));
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form">
                        <div class="alert" style="display: none;"></div>
                        <form class="form-validate form-horizontal " id="register_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">                             
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <div>
                                    <input class=" form-control" placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" />

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <div>
                                    <input class=" form-control" placeholder="Last Name" id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <div>
                                    <input class=" form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email_id" name="email_id" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <div>
                                    <input class="form-control country-code" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" type="tel" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Registration number" id="reg_no" name="reg_no">
                                </div>
                            </div>                          
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <div>
                                    <input class="form-control " placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" type="password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <div>
                                    <input class="form-control " placeholder="Re-enter Password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div>
                                    <button type="submit" id="btnRegister" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>                          
                    </div>
```

JS:

```
 // Submit registration form on button click last_name:{ required: true},
 $('form#register_form').validate({
  rules: {
    first_name: {
        required: true,
        alpha: true
    },       
    email_id: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    phone_number: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        minlength: 8,
        maxlength: 10
    },

    password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6
    },
    confirm_password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6,
        equalTo: "#password"
    },             
},
messages: {
    first_name: {
        required: "Please enter First Name.",
        alpha: "Special Characters not allowed."
    },        
    email_id: {
        required: "Please enter a email address.",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address."
    },
    phone_number: {
        required: "Please enter Phone Number." ,
        number: "Please enter Numeric values for Phone Number."
    },               
    password: {
        required: "Please provide a password.",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long."
    },
    confirm_password: {
        required: "Please provide a password.",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long.",
        equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above."
    },              
},
submitHandler: function(form) {
    var post_data = $("#register_form").serializeArray();

    //var phoneExten = $("ul.country-list li.active").attr('data-dial-code');
    var phoneExt = $("#phone_number").intlTelInput("getNumber");        
    post_data.push({name: "phone_number_with_ext", value: phoneExt});        
    //console.log(post_data);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/createAccount",
        type: "POST",
        data: post_data
    }).done(function(res) {
        //console.log(res);            
        var data = $.parseJSON(res);            
        if( data.success){
        $('form#register_form div.form div.alert').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').text('User Created Successfully.').show().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
        }else{
            $('div.form div.alert').addClass('alert-danger').text(data.error_msg.message).show().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            $("div.form").scrollTop();
        }
    });
     }
    });
```

Added success message in javascript it is working fine for failure message but not working for success message and once data is submitting it is displaying the data still in form fields.Not getting the data cleared.

Comment: Where do you want to add success message?

Answer (score 0):

Following line work like: first it find from#register_form withing the elements it next find div.form (which isn't inside the form#register_form) then jquery try to find div.alert withing div.form which is not found in your current HTML structure.

div.form is parent node of form#register_form.

```
$('form#register_form div.form div.alert').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').text('User Created Successfully.').show().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
```

You should change it to:

```
$('div.alert').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').text('User Created Successfully.').show().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
```

As far as you're submitting form through AJAX you need to clear out all form fields using jquery. You can do it like.

```
$('form#register_form').trigger("reset");
```

Comment: It is not displaying success message and clearing the fields

Comment: Yes i have checked with that as well but not displaying success message

Comment: getting this error in console  POST http://dev.localhost.in/createAccount 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Did you get form fields cleared? Do you see the message just after ajax call or you want to show it ever after reloading the page?

Comment: 500 error is from server side. do check your server side code.

Answer (score 0):

After end of the code use this line to refresh the page:

```
redirect('Login/createAccount','refresh');
```

For Success message:
In Controller Code:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('Add', 'Your da`ta added Successfully..');
 redirect('Login/createAccount','refresh');
```

In View page after body:

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('Add')){ ?>
    <center><div id="successMessage" class="alert bg-success alert-styled-left">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <span class="text-semibold"><?php echo  $this->session->flashdata('Add'); ?></span> 
</div></center>
<?php }  ?>
```

Javascript code for disable the flash data after particular time:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#successMessage").delay(5000).slideUp(300);
});
</script>
```

Comment: need to display success message as well if i refresh the page success message will not be displayed

Comment: you want   only in java script

Comment: getting this error in console POST http://dev.localhost.in/createAccount 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: why you are using ajax to save the data into the table?

Comment: i haven't used this was developed long back

Comment: it is view page code:<div class="form" id="form">  after success in ajax write this code
               document.getElementById("form").reset();

Comment: have you got any result or not?

Comment: use after success functioon in ajax $("#form")[0].reset();

Comment: or use this$ ('input[type="text"]'').val('');